# Counting automatic timestamps per interval in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a form my employees use to record completed tasks. I rely on the automatic timestamps generated by the form for accuracy. Here is where I need help:

I used COUNTIFS to count how many tasks were completed per hour. Since the form receives responses regularly within the shift, the formula does its work accurately. The problem is I have to change my formula to match the date. And I have 15 employees doing tasks. It is a pain in the neck to have to change the formula per interval (a total of 8 per day) for each of the 15 employees. I was wondering if there is an easier way?

Here is the example of the formula I use for 1 employee, for 1 interval. Add 7 more of these to get the other hourly intervals (3,4,5,6 PM etc):

=countifs(Time, ">=08/21/2021 2:00:00 PM", Time, "<=08/21/2021 2:59:00 PM", Name, "=John Smith")

And also imagine I need to change the date also. It is a very long process, and I hope someone has a simplified solution.

I don't think I can separate the timestamp by date and time to make it easier, because the form updates when an employee enters a completed task. I need the data available and in view all the time, that's why I chose this route. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your timestamps are in column A, and employee names in column B, use the following formula:

```
=query({arrayformula(text(A1:A,"yyyy-MM-dd")),arrayformula(text(A1:A,"HH")),A1:B},"select Col1, Col2, Col4, count(Col4) where Col4 is not null group by Col1, Col2, Col4 order by Col1, Col2, Col4 label Col1 'date', Col2 'hour', Col4 'employee', count(Col4) 'tasks completed'",1)
```

You can check an example at (make a copy of the sheet):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17g7Z8fARbWee0-y1evMhhLY5qVSiq2U-VMu_C2SNmXU/copy

Comment: Thanks for helping. This saved me 30 minutes of pre-shift formula editing! :) I cannot thank you enough! :)

Comment: Hi @Goran, thank you for your assistance. The formula worked wonders. I have one more question, hoping you could also help. I want to pull up historical data by selecting specific dates and then have the tasks completed for that date populate cells. I tried using the normal COUNT formula, but it does not seem to be reading the cells. In the sheet you shared, I tried this: =COUNT(D:D, =K2) where K2 was the specific date I wanted to filter and display. I got an error and I am wondering what I did wrong. Thank you in advance for any assistance. :)

Comment: you probably want =countif(D:D,K2)